# Accessing the Settings of another application

Tags: c#, wpf, clickonce

I have application 1 and application 2.  App2 needs to verify that App1 is installed, and if it is it needs to access a property from the App1 Settings.

What would be the best way to go about this?

**UPDATE**
First, my apologies for never accepting an answer to this, I know it's over a year old now, but I got sidetracked immediately after asking this and then the project was changed, blah blah blah.  Mea culpa...

I'm back on it now and I still need to solve this problem, but now the applications are deployed via ClickOnce, so I don't actually know where they are located.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.  I promise I'll select an answer this time.

Comment: Need more information.  Is the file location containing the settings already known?

Comment: Application scoped or user scoped settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs for ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration have an example of reading the .config file of another exe and accessing the AppSettings. Here it is:

```
// Get the application path.
string exePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(
    Environment.CurrentDirectory, "ConfigurationManager.exe");

// Get the configuration file.
System.Configuration.Configuration config =
  ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(exePath);

// Get the AppSetins section.
AppSettingsSection appSettingSection = config.AppSettings;
```

As far as checking that App1 is installed, you could write a value in the Registry during installation and check it in App2 (and remove the value during uninstall).

Answer (score 0):

This is a pain, I can tell you that much. I've found that the best way to do this is that you serialize the Settingsclass and use XML(code below). But try this page first:
http://cf-bill.blogspot.com/2007/10/visual-studio-sharing-one-file-between.html

```
public class Settings
{
    public static string ConfigFile{get{return "Config.XML";}}
    public string Property1 { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Saves the settings to the Xml-file
    /// </summary>
    public void Save()
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Settings));
        using (TextWriter reader = new StreamWriter(ConfigFile))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(reader, this);
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Reloads the settings from the Xml-file
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Settings loaded from file</returns>
    public static Settings Load()
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Settings));
        using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(ConfigFile))
        {
            return serializer.Deserialize(reader) as Settings;
        }
    }
}
```